# PHP POST paradox error

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress for a project and I have notice an unusual condition paradox.

```
<li class="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['search']) && $_REQUEST['search']!='opportunities')? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="#tabs-1" >People</a></li>
<li class="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['search']) && $_REQUEST['search']=='opportunities')? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="#tabs-2">Opportunities</a></li>
```

so when I submit a form, i'm getting the following.

```
$_POST['search'] =>'opportunities'
```

this is illogical for me to figure it out, just wondering if someone has come across this, and might help.

**UPDATE: sorry my bad...**

this is what I get back

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tabs-1" >People</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#tabs-2">Opportunities</a></li>
```

This is the paradox, how can they both have active classes??

I have used `$_POST` as well instead of `$_REQUEST` just for the record.

**Update 2**

After some more testing, and head banging moments later...

this paradox only happens when the `$_POST['search']='opportunities'`

Comment: I don't understand. How is the code executing?

Comment: I am sorry guys I forgot to put what I get on the sourcecode which is updated now ... sorry again [so you can tell how mad this is driving me]

Comment: Insert a `var_dump($_REQUEST['search']);` just before the `echo` in each statement and see what it says.

Comment: @BoltClock I have tried it says `string(13) "opportunities"` also read `update 2` above thats another clue there.

Comment: @BoltClock false alarm, apparently it was some javascript thing I had done, to select the first tab by default `$('.tabs li',n).eq(0).addClass('active');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just me being stupid, and my browser being toooooo fast that it seems,

problem was on a jquery script that automatically makes the first tab active, hence why they are both active...and that was not done by me which explains it all...

`$('.tabs li').eq(0).addClass('active');`

thank you guys, sometimes simple things, like this, make you wanna scream :)

Answer (score 2):

It basically says, if search is not 'opportunities', people is active.
If search is 'opportunities', opportunities is active.

This essentially is saying, people should be the default tab, and if any of the others are set, make them active. You only have one tab, so it's confusing.

Here is how it could look, if you had more tabs, in pseudo code.

```
(!in_array($_POST['search'], array('a', 'b', 'c')) ? 'active' : ''
$_POST['search'] == 'a' ? 'active' : ''
$_POST['search'] == 'b' ? 'active' : ''
$_POST['search'] == 'c' ? 'active' : ''
```

This is done by using the Ternary If to assign a CSS class.

`$name = (condition) ? (if true) : (if false);`

Comment: my bad, I didn't print the output, which is where the paradox comes to

Comment: I only need the two, either people, or opportunities, there wont be no more, hence why I used that,